# SQL Server - tricky query to update contact id using ROW_NUMBER to reference index value

Tags: sql-server

A previous developer used an index rather than the actual contactID to reference which of the associated contacts are the primary contact.  The index works well when the app gets the contacts and sets the primary contact in the list on the page, but try joining for a report!  Not easy; so I want to update the main table with the actual contact ID to make for a simple join and to avoid this buggary.

In this particular case, I need to update `tblInquiry` with the claimantContactID and agentContactID.  Those two fields I just created and defaulted to 0.  However, the challenge is to use the claimantContactIndex and agentContactIndex values from `tblInquiry`, to get the respective nth row from `tblContacts`.  The index is 0 based, so if the index value is 2, then get the ID of the 3rd contact, for example.

Also, claimantContactIndex and agentContactIndex can either be NULL or some number.  If NULL, then assume the first contact (index 0).

I will also add that the contacts index cannot have an order by on it because the application relies upon the natural order when getting the contacts list (there is no order by in the stored procedure), and selects then the index accordingly.

DB Platform:  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

I have the following table structure:

tblInquiry

```
    id | claimantID | agentID | claimantContactIndex | agentContactIndex | claimantContactID | agentContactID
    --------------------------------
    1 | 1001 | 2001 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0
    2 | 1002 | NULL | 0 | NULL | 0 | 0
```

tblClaimant

```
     id | name | address | phone | email 
    --------------------------------
    1001 | Widgets Inc. | 123 W. Main | 5550000 | widgets@here.com
    1002 | Thingies LLC. | 456 W. Main | 5551111 | thingies@here.com
```

tblAgent

```
    id | name | address | phone | email 
    --------------------------------
    2001 | Simon Bros. | 789 W. Main | 5552222 | simon@here.com
```

tblContacts

```
     id | claimantID | agentID | fn | ln | phone | email 
    --------------------------------
    3001 | 1001 | NULL | John | Doe | 5553333 | john@here.com
    3002 | 1001 | NULL | Fred | Flynn | 5554444 | fred@here.com
    3003 | 1001 | NULL | Mike | Brown | 55555555 | mike@here.com
    3004 | 1001 | NULL | Susan | Pierce | 5556666 | susan@here.com
    3005 | NULL | 2001 | Jeff | Bridges | 5557777 | jeff@here.com
    3006 | NULL | 2001 | Karry | Sinclair | 5558888 | Karry@here.com
    3007 | NULL | 2001 | Steve | Green | 5559999 | steve@here.com
    3008 | NULL | 2001 | Peter | White | 5550001 | peter@here.com
```

Update:
I have worked out the select part of this solution and I can now get the correct claimant contact info using ROW_NUMBER() and a JOIN. I will add more to get correct agent contact info. I also handled the case where an index is NULL. And ultimately I will work this out to update the inquiry table now that I have the right contactID.

```
SELECT 
    i.id inquiryID, i.claimantContactIndex, i.agentContactIndex, i.claimantContactID, i.agentContactID
    ,r.id contactID, r.claimantID, r.agentID
    ,r.*
FROM 
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (Partition by con.claimantid Order by (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber, *
    FROM tblContacts con
    ) r
INNER JOIN
    tblInquiry i on i.claimantid = r.claimantid and ((isnull(i.claimantContactIndex, 0) + 1 = r.RowNumber ))
WHERE
    i.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY
    i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by doing the following:

- As I posted above, using ROW_NUMBER() and (SELECT NULL()) along with an isnull to handle null values to get the correct contacts.
- I selected the results into a temp table.
- I then updated the inquiry table by joining it to the temp table.
- dropped temp table

I had to do this in two passes, once for claimants, a second time for agents.

Thx @EricH for pointing  me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

Using ideas from here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS RowNumber, 
    claimantID, agentID, (etc...)
FROM 
    tblContacts
```

To get an index based resultset. I'd drop it into a temp table and select from that where RowNumber = Whatever index you want.

Comment: Yes, I inherited this lovely application, warts and all...and as you can see I am trying to remedy this poor design decision.  I'll be updating 80,000 plus inquiry records...

Comment: I will also add that the contacts index cannot have an order by on it because the application relies upon the natural order when returning the contacts list, and selects the index accordingly.  I think using (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) accomplishes  that...

Comment: Yikes, I wish you luck. And I believe you're right on the Order By re: preserving row order. I has assumed the ID had a PK on it which (unless I'm wrong) defaults the sort order.